# node.js for microchip pic32

Tags: embedded, node.js, pic, microchip

I know lua is working on microchip PIC32 and I wonder if node.js (a javascript for server) could work on it too or if the lib will be too big or too slow for a PIC32.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering the processor power of 80MhZ and the RAM size of 128Kb: no.

The binary of nodejs itself is much larger than that, all dependencies left out (think of openssl and al c-libraries node depends on...).

Conclusion: node.js is too big and PIC32 is too slow.

Comment: he can try an ARM7 based micro, it's much larger but anyway, what a crazy idea :)